# Debugging CUDA kernels with VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, cuda

I am trying to debug a CUDA application on VS Code.

Configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- VSCode 1.56.2
- CUDA 11.3
- gcc/g++ 9.3

For this, I have the following (up to date) extensions:

- C/C++
- Nsight Visual Studio Code Edition

I have no problem compiling/running my program. However when I'm debugging, I am able to use the debugger correctly in CPU side but not on GPU side. Indeed, when I'm trying to add a breakpoint anywhere in the kernel, running the program always moves my breakpoint to the closing bracket and I can't see the variables.

Here are the files:

### add.cu

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(float *x, float *y)
{
    y[blockIdx.x] = x[blockIdx.x] + y[blockIdx.x];
}

int main(void)
{
  const int N = 1<<20;

  float *x, *y;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  add<<<N, 1>>>(x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);
  
  return 0;
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(add CUDA)

# add the executable
add_executable(add add.cu)
```

### .vscode/launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CUDA C++: Launch",
            "type": "cuda-gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/add"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm compiling this way:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build .
```

Every program I am trying do the exact same thing on any kernel breakpoint.

What do I miss here?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you have selected the proper launch configuration for debugging.   See [here](https://youtu.be/gN3XeFwZ4ng?t=70). Furthermore, its not clear to me that your build process is building with the appropriate device debug switches (`-G`).

Comment: I think the debug configuration is OK (there is no other existing template about CUDA), they probably changed some names since the video on your link. I'll check for the `-G` flag, you are right maybe cmake in debug mode does not add it to compilation. I'll check that.

Comment: You are right, the command run by cmake is `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -g -x cu -c /home/bbarrois/Workspace/cuda/easy-tutorial/add.cu -o CMakeFiles/add.dir/add.cu.o` so I shoud try adding the flag manually.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what do you see when you run `cmake --version`?

Comment: To be honest, 2 years later I'm not sure I'd get the same result ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by forcing `-G` flag when in debug mode in cmake, adding the following lines after `add_executable`:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_options(add PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-G>)
endif()
```

With this, debugging on device works.

Thanks @RobertCrovella for the tip.

Comment: I step through my code and when I get to a `cudaMallocManaged()` line the highlight for the current line of execution disappears and in the Call Stack window it says `(CUDA) selected thread is running` and it also shows arrows for stepping over, into, out of and Continue but when I try to click any of those it says, "Cannot execute command while selected thread is running."

Comment: I'm surprised that this is necessary. Usually CMake does stuff like this automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Benjamin's answer has a technical problem: With multi-config generators, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is not meaningful. The proper way to handle multi-config is to use [the `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:CONFIG). The modified answer would be like this I think:

```
target_compile_options(my_target PRIVATE "$<$<AND:$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>,$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>>:-G>")
```