# How to debug CUDA in VSCode on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, cuda, vscode-debugger

I've been using VSCode on Windows to learn CUDA development, but I can't find a way to use a debugger with my program.

I have Nsight Visual Studio Code Edition installed, but when I launch the debugger I get the message `Unable to launch cuda-gdb on non-Linux system`. After looking up the problem and seeing that it is indeed not supported, I saw that the solution appears to be to use Nsight *Visual Studio* edition with Nsight Monitor, which doesn't help me if I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Every guide or tutorial I've seen has either been Visual Studio on Windows, or Visual Studio Code on Linux.

So, do I have to use Visual Studio (and not VSC) if I want to use a debugger?

Comment: You cannot debug on a windows target from NVIDIA NSight VSCE, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-code-edition/install-setup/index.html#system-requirements). It is not a supported target.  There is no NVIDIA offered debugger solution for this combination.  It is unsupported.  If you want to debug on a windows target you must use NSight VSE.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76060559/11107541 ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67888279/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/72562128/11107541